# htaccess file with complex conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a complex mod rewrite rule that I need to get working. The situation is that I have a client whos domain utilizes HTTPS but on a specific section needs to be HTTP to allow websockets to work.
What I need to do is the following:
If the url has '/view-auctions/' string in it and it does not have /login/ in the url then it needs to serve up HTTP. Else it needs to server HTTPS. 
Here is what I have so far

```
  # for /view-auctions/ enforce http
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /view-auctions/ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # except for /view-auctions/ enforce https
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /view-auctions/ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This works well except there is a url that has both '/login/' '/view-auctions/' in the url at the same time when they both appear in the URL it should be HTTPS not HTTP.

I have looked all over google and here on stackoverflow but as of yet I have not found a sane way to achieve this. Admittidly my understanding of htaccess files is on a beginners level.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So after some more fiddling and reading the documentation further I got it. I am providing the answer to help others in similar situations and hopefuly provide a bit more clarity for those who are having similar issues.

One of the main things I found most confusing was figuring out the overal logic and control stuctures used in htaccess files. I had originally thought that I was going to need a  statement. What I figured out that I was over complicating things.

For the most part htaccess files are processed topdown and follow the directives in the order they appear in the file. Keep in mind that this means YOU CAN accidentally override a previous declaration if you are not careful. The solutions was to add another line below the third line

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/login/ [NC]
```

So it looks like this

```
  # for /view-auctions/ enforce http
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /view-auctions/ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/login/ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # except for /view-auctions/ enforce https
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /view-auctions/ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Because of the way the previous developer created the system and the client wanted to utilize SSL Certs I had to find a way to allow all the '/view-auctions/' URLs to display HTTP so that websockets would still work. Then I had to make sure that IF '/login/' AND '/view-auctions/' was in the URL that I served it up on a HTTPS connection.

So I first test to see if '/view-auctions/' is in the URL, then I test to make sure that '/login/' IS NOT in the URL. This way as long as '/login/' IS NOT in the URL the '/view-auctions/' URLs would continue to function on HTTP.

Admittidley I may not be explaining this in the best way as I said in my OP that I am a beginner at best with working in depth with htaccess files.